# I am trying to put tabs within an accordion

Tags: jquery, tabs, accordion

I downloaded the accordion and tabs from the jQueryUI website. Pretty simple stuff - didn't really do any programming of my own, just nested the tabs within the accordion.

Now, the tabs work just fine for the default accordion (the one that appears onload) but they will not show up within the accordion when you click on another pane of the accordion. Could anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

Let me know if you need more info. I am a big noobie.

Comment: I would recommend not to put tabs into an accordion - it's not the most optimal thing to do from a usability perspective.

Comment: @Tom - could you elaborate on this? I'm very interested to know why, and I haven't heard this reasoning before.

Comment: @Tom I would like to try however. The tabs seem to be working fine in the default accordion. Here is the script in the header. I also have the external scripts if anyone would like to see them:

Comment: $(function(){

    // Accordion
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });
    
    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
     function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
     function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
    );
    
   });

Comment: $(function tabss(){
 
    // Tabs
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    
    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
     function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
     function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
    );
    
   });

Comment: @sscirrus: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tom - just a sentence would be helpful enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RTfY7/)**

I suspect the reason it wasn't working for you is because the tabs need to have unique id's.

Since there are multiple "tab" sections, I gave them a class of tabs instead of an id, that way you can select all of them when you initialize the tabs.

**Your JS would simply look like this.**

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: false
});
$(".tabs").tabs();
```

**Your HTML would look like this**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
                <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
                <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-4">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-5">Proin dolor</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-6">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-4">
                <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-5">
                <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-6">
                <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
                <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
            Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
            ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
            lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
            et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
            faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
            mauris vel est.
        </p>
        <p>
            Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
            Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
            inceptos himenaeos.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```